# Geo Location based iPhone Applcation

Tags: iphone, location

Anyone having sample application links which could help me to find locations near by me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[CLLocation Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html)

[LocateMe Sample Application](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/LocateMe/index.html)

- these links require you to be a member of the Apple iPhone Developer Center.